# Are Picture or Hyperlink Sharepoint column types supported for quick part fields in Word templates?

Tags: list, word, library, quick-parts

I have a word document which has been created as a template for a list.  One of the list fields has been configured as a Hyperlink or Picture field.  I need to add the URL link to a document in another library on the same site.  There are a few workarounds I understand.

I can't see the Hyperlink or Picture declared field in my quick parts menu however this field appears in the document control panel at the top of the document.

I want to add my link list field as a quick part in the document.  This is more for user ease of use as they prefer using the standard Word input, not the control panel.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Comment: I did not no.  Sorry for the late reply.  I have not logged into this for a while.